# How to import data from csv to models using django-import-export?

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I've  made some researches about django-import-export, but the most of example I have found are using django admin..
I'm trying  to import  data to a django model from my template (when clicking on a button a modal appears to choose file location and then submit ),

I feel lost and I don't know how to start..

This is the model I have :

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

could someone guide me by giving the steps to follow ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I have not used django-import-export but writing a view for CSV generation is not difficult using python's built-in csv module.

Django docs also have a section on [outputting csv](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/).

Following is a snippet based on example provided in docs:

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class CsvExportView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        # create a response object
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        # assign a filename for csv
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format("filename.csv")
        wr = csv.writer(response, dialect='excel')
        # get queryset
        queryset = Musician.objects.all()
        # write every queryset to response object
        for obj in queryset:
            row = [obj.first_name, obj.last_name, obj.instrument]
            wr.writerow(row)
        # return response object
        return response
```